# configure colors in hexl-mode emacs

Tags: emacs, hex

I would like to configure the colors of different sections of data when displayed with hexl-mode.

For example, I would like the address ranges to be with white background,
the bytes in yellow, and the ASCII in red (whatever).

00000000: 2550 4446 2d31 2e34 0a25 c7ec 8fa2 0a35  %PDF-1.4.%.....5
00000010: 2030 206f 626a 0a3c 3c2f 4c65 6e67 7468   0 obj.<

I tried updating my color-theme like that:

```
 (hexl-address-region ((t (:background "#252525"))))
 (hexl-ascii-region ((t (:foreground "#cfbfad"))))
```

But it's obviously not working. The colors are not changed :(

My full color theme:

```
(eval-when-compile
   (require 'color-theme))

(defun sublime-text-2 ()
   "Color theme that looks like the Sublime Text 2 editor."
   (interactive)
   (color-theme-install
    '(sublime-text-2
      ((background-color . "#171717")
       (background-mode . light)
       (border-color . "#1a1a1a")
       (cursor-color . "#fce94f")
       (foreground-color . "#cfbfad")
       (mouse-color . "black"))
       (fringe ((t (:background "#1a1a1a"))))
       (mode-line ((t (:foreground "#eeeeec" :background "#555753"))))
       (region ((t (:foreground "#404040" :background "#CC9900"))))
       (font-lock-builtin-face ((t (:foreground "#52e3f6"))))
       (font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground "#ffffff"))))
       (font-lock-function-name-face ((t (:foreground "#edd400"))))
       (font-lock-keyword-face ((t (:foreground "#ff007f"))))
       (font-lock-string-face ((t (:foreground "#ece47e"))))
       (font-lock-type-face ((t (:foreground"#8ae234"))))
       (font-lock-variable-name-face ((t (:foreground "#8ae234"))))
       (minibuffer-prompt ((t (:foreground "#729fcf" :bold t))))
       (font-lock-warning-face ((t (:foreground "Red" :bold t))))
       (hexl-address-region ((t (:background "#252525"))))
       (hexl-ascii-region ((t (:foreground "#cfbfad"))))
       (speedbar-directory-face ((t (:foreground "light blue"))))
       (speedbar-tag-face ((t (:foreground "#cfbfad"))))
 )))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your problem. There seems to be a problem with hexl-mode where it does not fontify the buffer when the mode starts.

To force `hexl-mode` to fontify the buffer, add this to your .emacs

```
(require 'hexl)
(add-hook 'hexl-mode-hook 'font-lock-fontify-buffer)
```

I also filed a bug report about the issue.

Comment: I added that to the .emacs, before the colors are read, but absolutely no change: no color in hexl mode...

Comment: Try running m-x font-lock-fontify-buffer when already in hexl-mode, if that doesn't work. Do m-x describe-face on the text in hexl and verify that your color changes are actually going through.